# .Net 6 authentication with JWT token and OpenIDConnect Microsoft Login

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

Im trying to Migrate a .net framework MVC project to .NET 6 API project. There are already users present in the aspnetusers table. I need to setup an authentication where some users will login with username and password while others Sign in with Microsoft. So implemented an endpoint to generate a JWT token for users to login with password and trying to use OpenIDConnect to sign in with microsoft.
How we can make use of the [Authorize] attribute for both these cases? Do we need to generate JWT token on the call back of microsoft login also?
Providing my startup.cs code for reference.Please let me know if anything wrong

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
ConfigurationManager configuration = builder.Configuration;

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

RSA rsa = RSA.Create();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnStr")));


builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", o =>
{
    o.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
    {
        OnMessageReceived = (ctx) =>
        {
            if (ctx.Request.Query.ContainsKey("t"))
            {
                ctx.Token = ctx.Request.Query["t"];
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

    };
    o.Configuration = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfiguration()
    {
        SigningKeys =
        {
            new RsaSecurityKey(rsa)
        }
    };
    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
    };
    o.MapInboundClaims = false;
})
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", o =>
{
    o.ClientId = "[clientId]";
    o.ClientSecret = "[secret]";
    o.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/Common/v2.0";
    o.CallbackPath = "/signin-microsoft";
    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false
    };
});
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
      .AddCookie(options =>
      {
        options.Cookie.Name = "CookieName";
      });
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
   
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();


app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
app.MapGet("/authorize", async () =>
{
    using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
    {
       
        var userManager = (UserManager<IdentityUser>)scope.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(UserManager<IdentityUser>));
        var roleManager = (RoleManager<IdentityRole>)scope.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(RoleManager<IdentityRole>));
        var signInManager = (SignInManager<IdentityUser>)scope.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(SignInManager<IdentityUser>));
     


        var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync("useremail@mail.com", "password", false, false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var key = new RsaSecurityKey(rsa);
            var handler = new JsonWebTokenHandler();
            var token = handler.CreateToken(new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
            {
               
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]{
            new Claim("sub",Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            new Claim("id",Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            new Claim("name","denny")
        }),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256)
            });
            return token;
        }
        return null;
    }
});
```

How can we switch the authentication to Microsoft login from an endpoint?